# External css can't load on IE7,8,9,10,11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

External **CSS** can not load on Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9, 10, 11. How can I resolve it?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: seems to me that the css files are local not external ?

Comment: this is the external css

Comment: Are you checked your code work in other browsers like chrome, Firefox, safari. If  ans yes then please check your IE browser setting option.

Comment: yes every browser work perfectly except ie. which settings should i changed. can you tell me please?